# How to locate files in a filesystem that are php files and chmod them to 655 in shell

Tags: shell, chmod

I was told this would help me chmod directories:

find . -type 'd' -exec chmod 755 {} \;

that worked.

But how can I find php files and chmod them to 644 recursively?

is there a similar command to do that? just files ending in .php?

Thanks

Comment: Try 'find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; or read the manual page of find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

find . -type 'f' -name '*.php' -exec chmod 644 {} \;

and it worked.

glad I did not break anything...